# Find the first $4$ Hermite polynomials using a recursion relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, intuition

Given the Probabilists' Hermite differential equation: $$U''-xU'+\lambda U=0\tag{1}$$
`A book question asks me to:`

> Find the first $4$ polynomial solutions (for $\lambda = 0,1,2,3$), each normalised such that the highest power of $x$ has a coefficient of unity.

---

So I substituted $$U=\sum_{n=0}^{\lambda}C_nx^n\tag{2}$$ into $(1)$ and equated coefficients of $x^n$ to get the recursion relation:
$$C_{n+2}=\frac{(n-\lambda)}{(n+1)(n+2)}C_n$$

So I am looking to find the values of the coefficients $C_0,C_1,C_2$ for $$U=\sum_{n=0}^{3}C_nx^n=C_0+C_1x+C_2x^2+x^3$$
where we are given that $\color{blue}{C_3}=1$.

Using the recursion relation I find that for $(n=0, \lambda=2)$: $$C_2=-C_0$$ 
and for $(n=1, \lambda=3)$: $$\color{blue}{C_3}=-\frac13C_1\implies C_1=-3$$

This is as far as I can get to in this question.

---

`The book answer simply states:`

> Using the recurrence relations, and setting the coefficient of the
>   highest power to $1$, $U_0=1, \,U_1=x,\, U_2=x^2-1\,$ and $U_3=x^3-3x$

I know from [this page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) that the book answer is right, but the answer is not very helpful to me as I have no idea why $U_0=1$. Does this mean that $C_0=1$, if so how did the author deduce this from the recursion relation? I showed that $C_1$ is equal to $-3$. So why is $U_1\ne-3x$? The same misunderstanding follows for $U_2$ and $U_3$. In fact I don't understand why $U_3$ doesn't contain an $x^2$ term and a constant term. Also, where is the $x$ term in $U_2$ and the constant term in $U_1$?

I have only just started reading about Hermite polynomials so my understanding is very weak (apologies).

Is there any chance someone could explain as simply as possible how to obtain $U_0,U_1,U_2,U_3$?

Thank you.

Comment: My first guess is that different choices of $\lambda$ lead to different solutions of the DE, and hence to different values for the constants $C_i$. In other words, $C_i$ might be written as $C_i(\lambda)$, because their values depend on $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two aspects: One addresses the  recurrence relation, the other the different polynomial  solutions.

> - A  recurrence relation is **not specified** if the *initial values* are missing.
>
>   Here we consider a second-order recurrence relation 
>     \begin{align*}
>   (n+1)(n+2)C_{n+2}-(n-\lambda)C_n&=0\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\\
>   C_0&=???\tag{1}\\
>   C_1&=???\\
>   \end{align*}
>     parametrised with $\lambda=0,1,2,\ldots$.
>
>   Please note, in order to fully determine the recurrence relation it's crucial to also determine two initial values. These are usually $C_0$ and $C_1$ from which all other values with the help of the recurrence relation can be calculated.
>
>   The calculation of the *initial values* is independent from the calculation of the recurrence relation.

We observe due to the *special structure* of the recurrence relation that once we have determined $C_0$, we can calculate all evenly indexed values, and once we have determined $C_1$, we can calculate all oddly indexed value.
\begin{align*}
C_0&\qquad\rightarrow\qquad C_2, C_4, C_6, \ldots\\
C_1&\qquad\rightarrow\qquad C_3, C_5, C_7, \ldots\\
\end{align*}

> - For each parameter $\lambda=0,1,2,3$ a normalised polynomial $U_\lambda(x)$ with degree $\lambda$ 
>     \begin{align*}
>   U_\lambda(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\lambda C_n^{(\lambda)}x^n\\
>   \end{align*}
>     fulfilling the differential equation $U^{\prime\prime}-xU^\prime+\lambda U=0$ is to determine.
>
>   Since we have to find four different polynomials, it is convenient to use the parameter $\lambda$ as additional marker  to make the coefficients distinguishable and write $C_k^{(\lambda)}$.
>
>   The polynomials $U_\lambda$ we are looking for are
>
>   \begin{align*}
>   \lambda=0:\qquad&U_0(x)=1\\
>   \lambda=1:\qquad&U_1(x)=C_0^{(1)}+x\tag{2}\\
>   \lambda=2:\qquad&U_2(x)=C_0^{(2)}+C_1^{(2)}x+x^2\\
>   \lambda=3:\qquad&U_3(x)=C_0^{(3)}+C_1^{(3)}x+C_2^{(3)}x^2+x^3\\
>   \end{align*}
>
>   Here are four different polynomials $U_\lambda(x)$ with degree $\operatorname{deg}\left(U_\lambda(x)\right)=\lambda$ and coefficient of highest power equal  to $1$ since they have to be normalised.

---

> Calculation of the polynomials:
>
> - **Case:** $\lambda=0$
>
> Observe, that $U_0(x)=1$ is already given due to the degree requirement of the polynomial and the normalisation requirement. But we have to check that it is a proper solution which fulfills the differential equation.
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left(U_0(x)\right)^{\prime\prime}&-x\left(U_0(x)\right)^{\prime}+0\cdot U_0(x)=0-x\cdot0+0\cdot 1=0
> \end{align*}
>   and we have verified that $$U_0(x)=1$$ is the wanted polynomial for $\lambda=0$.
>
> - **Case:** $\lambda=1$
>
> In order to determine the missing coefficients of $U_1(x)$ we put it into the differential equation and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> 0&=\left(U_1(x)\right)^{\prime\prime}-x\left(U_1(x)\right)^{\prime}+U_1(x)\\
> &=0-x\cdot \left(1\right)+1\cdot \left(C_0^{(1)}+x\right)\\
> &=C_0^{(1)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> According to (3) we obtain $C_0^{(1)}=0$ and the polynomial $U_1(x)$ is according to (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> U_1(x)&=x+C_0^{(1)}\\
> &=x
> \end{align*}
>
> - **Case:** $\lambda=2$
>
> In order to determine the missing coefficients of $U_2(x)$ we put it into the differential equation and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> 0&=\left(U_2(x)\right)^{\prime\prime}-x\left(U_2(x)\right)^{\prime}+2U_2(x)\\
> &=2-x\left(C_1^{(2)}+2x\right)+2\left(C_0^{(2)}+C_1^{(2)}x+x^2\right)\\
> &=C_1^{(2)}x+2\left(C_0^{(2)}+1\right)\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> Comparing coefficient with equal powers in RHS and LHS of (4) gives 
>   \begin{align*}
> C_1^{(2)}&=0\\
> C_0^{(2)}&=-1
> \end{align*}
>   and the polynomial $U_2(x)$ is according to (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> U_2(x)&=x^2+C_1^{(2)}x+C_0^{(2)}\\
> &=x^2-1
> \end{align*}
>
> - **Case:** $\lambda=3$
>
> In order to determine the missing coefficients of $U_3(x)$ we put it into the differential equation and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> 0&=\left(U_3(x)\right)^{\prime\prime}-x\left(U_3(x)\right)^{\prime}+3U_3(x)\\
> &=\left(6x+2C_2^{(3)}\right)-x\left(3x^2+2C_2^{(3)}x+C_1^{(3)}\right)
> +3\left(C_0^{(3)}+C_1^{(3)}x+C_2^{(3)}x^2+x^3\right)\\
> &=C_2^{(3)}x^2+2\left(3+C_1^{(3)}\right)x+2C_2^{(3)}+3C_0^{(3)}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Comparing coefficient with equal powers in RHS and LHS of (4) gives 
>   \begin{align*}
> C_2^{(3)}&=0\\
> C_1^{(3)}&=-3\\
> C_0^{(3)}&=0
> \end{align*}
>   and the polynomial $U_3(x)$ is according to (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> U_3(x)&=x^3+C_2^{(3)}x^2+C_1^{(3)}x+C_0^{(3)}\\
> &=x^3-3x
> \end{align*}

*Notes:*

- We observe that  the recurrence relation (2) is not that helpful for *small* values of $\lambda$, since for $\lambda=0,1,2$ the calculation consists of determination of the initial values only. Just in the case $\lambda=3$ we could obtain $C_2^{(3)}$ from the initial value $C_0^{(3)}=0$.
- Nevertheless will the recurrence relation show its strength with increasing $\lambda$. It's also interesting to see that the coefficients depend oddly and evenly indexed from the the initial values.
- The nice fact that evenly indexed polynomials $U_{2\lambda}$ are *even* functions and oddly indexed polynomials $U_{2\lambda+1}$ are *odd* functions has to be analysed separately.

Comment: Very good answer Markus, a first class explanation!

Comment: @BLAZE: You're welcome! Thanks for your nice comment! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should add a second index to the recurrence formula in order to avoid confusion. 
$$C_{n+2}^{(\lambda)}=\frac{(n-\lambda)}{(n+1)(n+2)}C_n^{(\lambda)}$$
With this, it is an immediate consequence that in even indexed polynomial $U_0, U_2,\dots$ the odd coefficients $C_{1}^{(\lambda)}, C_{3}^{(\lambda)}$ are zero and analogous for the odd indexed polynomials. So you have the trivial cases

$$U_0(x)=1$$ 
$$U_1(x)=x$$

For $U_2(x) = C_{0}^{(2)} + x^2$ you get 
$$1=C_{2}^{(2)} = \frac{(0-2)}{(0+1)(0+2)}C_{0}^{(2)}$$
i.e. $\color{red}{C_{0}^{(2)}}=-1$ and $U_2(x)= x^2-1$.

For $U_3(x) = C_{1}^{(2)}x + x^3$ you get 
$$1=\color{red}{C_{3}^{(3)}} = \frac{(1-3)}{(1+1)(1+2)}C_{1}^{(3)}=-\frac{1}{3}C_{1}^{(3)}$$

i.e. $\color{red}{C_{1}^{(3)}}=-3$ and $U_2(x)= x^3-3x$.

Comment: How does it follow as an immediate consequence that the odd coefficients $C_1^{(\lambda)}, C_3^{(\lambda)}$ etc are necessarily zero for an even indexed polynomial?

Comment: @gammatester Thanks for your answer. How did you deduce that $U_0(x)=1$ and $U_1(x)=x$ (It's not that trivial to me)? My other question has already been asked in the above comment by okrzysik.

Comment: Since $n$ is related to $n+2$ by a factor, and the $C_{n}^{(\lambda)}=0$  for $n>\lambda$, i.e $0=C_{n+1}^{(n)} = C_{n-1}^{(n)} = C_{n-3}^{(n)} \dots$ The lowest polynomials: 
$U_0=1$ comes from $C_0^{(0)}=1,$ and $U_1=x$ from $C_1^{(1)}=1$ and the even zero coefficients.

Comment: $C_0^{(0)}=1, C_1^{(1)}=1$ come from the task's requirement _normalised such that the highest power of x has a coefficient of unity._

Comment: @gammatester You wrote that "$C_{n}^{(\lambda)}=0$ for $n\gt \lambda$". But the parts marked $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ (and other parts) in your answer violate this condition. Do you mean $C_{n}^{(\lambda)}=0$ for $n\le \lambda$?

Comment: No; they do **not** violate the condition, because $n=3 \not \gt \lambda = 3,\;$  $n=0 \not \gt \lambda = 3, $ and  $n=0 \not \gt \lambda = 2$. The condition just describes the fact that  $$U_{\lambda}=\sum_{n=0}^{\lambda}C_n^{(\lambda)}x^n\tag{2}$$
is a polynomial of degree $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

$$U''-xU'+\lambda U=0$$

This is more a long comment than an answer. If fact I only answer to  OP question : "I have no idea why $U_0 =1$. Does this mean that $C_0 =1$ ? " : See below the case $\lambda=0$.

The answer with the method of series and recurrence relations has already been given. No need to repeat it. Of course, it isn't a smart method that is  used below.

Case $\lambda=0 \quad\to\quad U''-xU'=0$

The polynomial solution comes from $U'=0 \quad\to\quad U=c=$constant.

This is the highest power of $x$ i.e.: $x^0$ . Taking account of the request of normalisation $c=1$

$$U_0(x)=1$$

Case $\lambda=1$

$U''-xU'+U=0\quad $Polynomial solution : $U=ax+b$

$(ax+b)''-x(ax+b)'+(ax+b)=0 \quad\to\quad \begin{cases} \text{any }a \\ b=0\end{cases} \quad\to\quad U=ax$

$a=1$ to be normalized.
$$U_1(x)=x$$

Case $\lambda=2$

$U''-xU'+2U=0\quad$ Polynomial solution $U=ax^2+bx+c$

$2a-x(2ax+b)+2(ax^2+bx+c)=0 \quad\to\quad \begin{cases} \text{any }a \\ b=0\\ c=-a\end{cases} \quad\to\quad U=ax^2-a$

$a=1$ to be normalized.
$$U_2(x)=x^2-1$$

Case $\lambda=3$

$U''-xU'+3U=0\quad$ Polynomial solution $U=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

$(6ax+2b)-x(3ax^2+2bx+c)+3(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=0$

$\begin{cases} \text{any }a \\b=0 \\ c=-3a \\ d=0\end{cases} \quad\to\quad U=ax^3-3a \qquad a=1$ to be normalized.
$$U_3(x)=x^3-3x$$

Case $\lambda=4$

$U''-xU'+4U=0\quad$ Polynomial solution $U=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+E$

$(12ax^2+6bx+2c)-x(4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d)+4(ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+E)=0$

$\begin{cases} \text{any }a \\b=0 \\ c=-6a \\ d=0 \\ E=3a\end{cases} \quad\to\quad U=ax^4-6ax^2+3a \qquad a=1$ to be normalized.
$$U_4(x)=x^4-6x^2+3$$

Comment: Hi there, thank you for a fabulous answer. I have just one question: For the case $\lambda=0 \quad\to\quad U''-xU'=0$ you wrote "The polynomial solution comes from $U′=0$". Why does the polynomial solution come from $U'=0$? Thanks.

Comment: @BLAZE: because obviously $U'=0$ satisfies the ODE and the general solution of $U'=0$ is a polynomial (of course the most elementary form of polynomial $U(x)=c\,x^0$ ).